# How to get HTTPS content using Python Requests through TOR and Privoxy

Tags: python, proxy, tor, python-requests

I have TOR setup on my system with Privoxy that has been tested and works well. What I am trying to do is proxy HTTPS requests through this setup, so that these GET and POSTs come through TOR. Below is the simplest version of the code I could produce:

```
import requests
proxy = { 'http':'127.0.0.1:8118','https':'127.0.0.1:8118' }
r = requests.get('https://www.whatismyip.com/',proxies=proxy)
#r = requests.get('http://www.whatsmyip.org/')
print r
```

When using HTTPS, I do not get the response body (r.content is blank), but I do get a 200 status code and I can see the request go out in the Privoxy logs. I saw a bug on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005301/https-proxy-support-in-python-requests-library) thread, but it appears that was solved in the Requests library months ago with [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/478).

My privoxy setup is the basic one and setup to listen on the localhost with the addition of the following two lines:

```
forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .
```

At this point I am not sure what's going on, but nothing I do seems to work. I am on Python 2.6.5 with the latest requests library and urllib3.

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS proxies are not yet properly supported by `urllib3` (used by `requests`).

Please see [requests issue 905](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/905) and [urllib3 issue 50](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/50) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`requesocks`](https://github.com/dvska/requesocks), a fork of `requests` designed to connect directly to a SOCKS proxy (like Tor is, without ever using Privoxy in the first place. If you need Privoxy specifically, you may be out of luck, but otherwise, `pip install requesocks` and replace

```
import requests
```

with

```
import requesocks
requests = requesocks.session()
requests.proxies = {"http": "socks5://127.0.0.1:8118",
                   "https": "socks5://127.0.0.1:8118"}
```

Now, the `requests` variable is a session (with `requests.get()` and friends) that you can use in the exact same way as directly importing `requests`.

Comment: Just realized this question is literally 4 years old. Derp.