# Why does Python's `requests` reject my SSL certificate, which browsers accept

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, python-requests

I recently got an SSL certificate for my site:

```
https://ram.rachum.com/
```

It works great in browsers. But it fails for `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://ram.rachum.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    requests.get('https://ram.rachum.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 354, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 460, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 250, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: hostname 'ram.rachum.com' doesn't match either of '*.webfaction.com', 'webfaction.com'
```

Why? Why does `requests` look at the webfaction certificate rather than my own certificate, which is valid for `ram.rachum.com`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a requests library without support for SNI (server name indication), but you have multiple SSL certificates behind the same IP address which requires SNI. You can verify this with `openssl s_client`. Without given a name for SNI the server just gives the default certificate for this IP, which is *.webfaction.com:

```
openssl s_client -connect ram.rachum.com:443
...
 0 ...CN=*.webfaction.com
```

But if you specify a hostname for SNI it returns the expected certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect ram.rachum.com:443 -servername ram.rachum.com
...
 0 ...CN=ram.rachum.com...
```

Maybe you need to upgrade your requests library and other modules too, see [using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support)

Comment: I too use webfaction, got the same error message, purchased a static IP upgrade (+$5/mo) but error persists. Ideas?

Comment: @MarcMaxson: please don't ask a question at some old answer. Better open  a new question with enough details (like domain name).