# Python requests and OpenSSL - HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, openssl, python-requests, pyopenssl

I have a problem using python requests library in Ubuntu 14.04 when execute the following script:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'code':'TG-000000000000000000000000', 'client_secret':'X0000000000000000000000000000000', 'grant_type':'authorization_code', 'client_id':'1111111111111111', 'redirect_uri':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mercadolibre/process_ml_response/'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
requests.post("https://api.mercadolibre.com:443/oauth/token", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I get the following traceback

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/tumoto/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/tumoto/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/tumoto/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/tumoto/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/theuser/.virtualenvs/tumoto/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.mercadolibre.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)
```

If I try the same code in Ubuntu 13.10 works fine

I guest this error is related to the version of openssl (1.0.1f) and requests python library

I try installing pyOpenSSL, ndg-httpsclient and pyasn1 as is suggested in [using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support) but doesn't work, also apply the monkey patch before run the script but also fails

Note: when I use pyOpenSSL then the new error that I get is:

```
request.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake](104, 'ECONNRESET')
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: "...as suggested in using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support ..." - I think you need Python3 for SNI (its been some time since I performed the particular testing).

Comment: I tried requests in python3 but this was not successful

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need Python 3.2 or higher. Are `api.py`, `sessions.py` and `adapters.py` Python3 compatible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a fork of requests that works fine with OpenSSL version of Ubuntu 14.04, https://github.com/joequery/requests-sslv3 only install this fork via pip and requests works well again