# Python 2.7.10 "requests" for HTTPS fails and "fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found"

Tags: python, macos, ssl, python-requests, pyopenssl

It seems very likely that the problem described in [Requests, Mechanize, urllib fails but cURL works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114094/requests-mechanize-urllib-fails-but-curl-works) is what I am experiencing.
I tried to execute the solution described there in [Requests, Mechanize, urllib fails but cURL works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114094/requests-mechanize-urllib-fails-but-curl-works#27220799) but I fail with

```
 sudo -H pip install pyOpenSSL==0.13 ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
  .
  .
 OpenSSL/crypto/x509.h:17:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
  #include <openssl/ssl.h>
           ^
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyOpenSSL
  Running setup.py clean for pyOpenSSL
Failed to build pyOpenSSL
```

Comment: You are missing openssl header files. You need to install the development headers.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: OK, I found out how to get the header files. Now I get another error:
    OpenSSL/crypto/crl.c:6:23: error: static declaration of 'X509_REVOKED_dup' follows non-static declaration

Comment: Yes because you are using an old version of Openssl. Just install the latest, `sudo -H pip install pyOpenSSL`

Comment: The above command (actually with --upgrade) starts by successfully doing stuff but at the end failed with 

Installing collected packages: setuptools, idna, ipaddress, enum34, cryptography, pyOpenSSL
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
 "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-X9k0Cu-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")

Comment: I can't really post the full output here because I am limited in characters - posted the beginning and the final Error message

Comment: You have not used sudo?

Comment: I did use sudo.
After more research, I discovered I have to do "csrutil disable" to allow overwriting OSX installed files.
After that I still got X509_REVOKED_dup but learnt that I should use pyOpenSSL==0.14.

But my original problem wasn't solved :-(
When using Python requests package to reach an https site I get:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')",)
which was the trigger for my other questions.

Comment: Yes, that is the same when you try to replace os owned packages on linux. What site are you visiting?

Comment: Finally fixed the issue by Brewing another Python, instead of usin the OSX suuplied one according to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022#issuecomment-41475570 .

It was happening on many https sites.

Comment: Yes, you have to compile your python against the newer version.