# Why is this SSLerror coming on sending request to any subdomain like sandbox.example.com?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, python, openssl

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("https://api.example.com/index.php")
<Response [200]>

>>> requests.get("https://sandbox.example.com/index.php")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: hostname 'sandbox.example.com' doesn't match either of 'example.com', 'account.example.com', 'api.example.com', 'secure.example s.com'
```

why is this error coming while `https://sandbox.example.com/index.php` and `https://api.example.com/index.php both` are working fine on browser?

Comment: Yes I did search for it on Stack overflow, but couldn't get something very helpful. So, I posted it here.

Answer (score 2):

Python3’s SSL module includes native support for [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This support has not been back ported to Python2. The remote server may be dependent on SNI to provide you with the correct certificate, hence the error.

For information on using SNI with Requests on Python2 refer to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484).

Comment: I installed all those three packages and again tried the same thing, but unfortunately it didn't work. Can you tell me, what else am I missing?

Comment: even I tried after installing urllib3, but that also didn't work.

Comment: SNI may not be your actual problem though. It is just something I ran into sometime ago that generates similar error messages. Are your browser and your code connecting to the same hosts for instance and not being influenced by a hosts file. Can you validate the certificates with openssl?