# Getting a webpage using requests is taking too long while dealing with Cloudflare server, but works quickly in browser and curl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, feedparser

I am trying to read a rss feed using feedparser. But the program gets stuck when using `requests`, `feedparser` or `urlopen`. The page I am trying to get is [here](http://mangastream.com/rss) (mangastream.com rss feed)

I can view it in browser or get it using curl in terminal.

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> feed = feedparser.parse('http://mangastream.com/rss')
```

It won't get past line 2.

[image]

Edit - Could this be an issue with cloudflare server? DoS/bot protection of some sort? But it works in curl. Not behind proxy or anything.

**Edit** - Somehow it's working but still takes a lot of time (more than 2-3 mins). It works lot faster with curl.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, can you give some more details about your setup?

Comment: `urllib` and `requests`works....

Comment: @JesseBakker Setup? :/ I am running Ubuntu, Python 3.5 inside virtualenv. I have tested with other url ( httpbin.org ) so python process can access the network.

Comment: Feedparser works for me, with similar setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Cloudflare on my side, Replacing hostname with IP address and passing domain name as `host` header is works.

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("http://104.28.18.11/rss", headers={'host':'mangastream.com'})
<Response [200]>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995307/7089190)