# how to go to a specific path of host using Python Requests?

Tags: python, request, python-requests, postman

I have this `host`: `http://retsau.torontomls.net:7890/`and I want to access `http://retsau.torontomls.net:7890/rets-treb3pv/server/login`, how can I accomplish this using Python Requests? All my attempts till now have failed.

I also followed the solution here - [Python Requests - Use navigate site by servers IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995133/python-requests-use-navigate-site-by-servers-ip) and came up with this -

`response = requests.get(http://206.152.41.279/rets-treb3pv/server/login, headers={'Host': retsau.torontomls.net})`

but that resulted in this error:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='206.152.41.279', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /rets-treb3pv/server/login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10a4f6d84>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',))`

Funny thing is everything seems to work perfectly fine on Postman, I am able to access all sorts of URLs on that server, from logging in to searching for something.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the port number (7890) from the URL to your `get` call:

```
response = requests.get('http://206.152.41.279:7890/rets-treb3pv/server/login', headers={'Host': 'retsau.torontomls.net'})
                                             # ^^^^ Add this
```

Also, unless you actually have a specific reason for accessing the site by IP address, it would make more sense to put the FQDN in the URL rather than the `Host` header:

```
response = requests.get('http://retsau.torontomls.net:7890/rets-treb3pv/server/login')
```

Comment: thanks for noticing that, I did try it, now I am getting `<Response [400]>`