# Python Requests SSL Error 504

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to connect to a login page(https page) using requests.
My code:

```
import requests
requests.get('https page')
```

This still returns:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I set `verify=False` but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server requires [SNI (server name indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and will cause a TLS alert if the SNI extension is not used. SNI is available with python 3 and with python 2.7.9+. For older versions of python see [using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484).

Answer (score 7):

Install requests module like this. This will install the security package extras.

```
pip install requests[security]
```