# Ubuntu Python requests pulling incorrect SSL cert

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, python-requests

The requests package in Python seems to reference the incorrect SSL cert in Ubuntu. I'm using requests 2.6.2.  The code runs fine on a Mac but fails on Ubuntu.  I appreciate any help!

This request:

```
query_string = https://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/links/youtube.com?Sort=page_authority&Source=page_to_page&Filter=internal&LinkCols=4&Limit=50&Offset=0

requests.get(query_string, auth=(self.accessid,self.key))
```

Produces this error output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       requests.get('https://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/links/youtube.com?Sort=page_authority&Source=page_to_page&Filter=internal&LinkCols=4&Limit=50&Offset=0')
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
>       response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/mark/venvs/nessus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   SSLError: hostname 'lsapi.seomoz.com' doesn't match either of 'incapsula.com', ...

Comment: Workaround: provide `verify=False` param to requests.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question boils down to being the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/): the version of Python you're using does not support SNI. Follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579484/1401686).