# requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'boxfwd.com' doesn't match either of 'nycmsk.com', 'www.nycmsk.com'

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

Very simple example on python:

```
import requests

c = requests.get(u'https://boxfwd.com').content
print c
```

And on my local computer all works fine.

But on server I see this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'boxfwd.com' doesn't match either of 'nycmsk.com', 'www.nycmsk.com'
```

Why I see this error on server ?

In browser I see certificate to *.boxfwd.com [image: certificate]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your server another domain (nycmsk.com) is also hosted and `requests` picks up that certificate.

Look here for a potential solution: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/#what-are-hostname-doesn-t-match-errors

Also probably duplicate with: [using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484)

Answer (score 0):

Same type of error I was getting while integrating my HAProxy with Datadog for monitoring.
Stacktrace:
 haproxy
    -------
      - instance #0 [ERROR]: '(\'Connection aborted.\', BadStatusLine("\'\'",))'
      - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

The reason was my EC2 box url was accessible with https that causes ssl was enable.After adding 'disable_ssl_validation: true' in my haproxy.yaml in data-agent/conf.d/haproxy.yaml it worked