# How to get the SSl certificate expiry date for IP address URL

Tags: java, ssl

I am undergoing a task to get the ssl expiration date for a domain website and one that is accessed via IP. I have written below code. When I give domain name it gives me correct ouput but when I give Ip address in URl i.e. 192.168.1.1 it throws javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version error. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong here

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://google.co.in");
    System.out.println("Expiration Date: "+getCertificateExpiration(url));
}

/**
 * Returns the expiration (notAfter) date of the X.509 Certificate
 * used to encrypt the HTTPS connection of the given URL.  If the
 * connection is not a secure HTTPS connection or the server is not
 * signed with an X.509 certificate, this method returns null.  You
 * may want to modify the implementation to throw relevant
 * exceptions if you need to handle those conditions separately.
 * @param url the URL to connect to
 * @return the expiration (notAfter) date of the server's X.509 Certificate or
 * null if unable to connect, the connection is not secure, or the server is
 * not signed with an X.509 certificate.
 */
public static Date getCertificateExpiration(URL url) {
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            /*retrieve the N-length signing chain for the server certificates.
            certs[0] is the server's certificate.
            certs[1] - certs[N-1] are the intermediate authorities that signed the cert.
            certs[N] is the root certificate authority of the chain. */
            Certificate[] certs = ((HttpsURLConnection)conn).getServerCertificates();
            if (certs.length > 0 && certs[0] instanceof X509Certificate) {
                // certs[0] is an X.509 certificate, return its "notAfter" date
                return ((X509Certificate)certs[0]).getNotAfter();
            }
        }
        // connection is not HTTPS or server is not signed with an X.509 certificate, return null
        return null;
    } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException spue) {
        // connection to server is not verified, unable to get certificates
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        // shouldn't get here -- indicates attempt to get certificates before
        // connection is established
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // error connecting to URL -- this must be caught last since
        // other exceptions are subclasses of IOException
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error Stacktrace is as follows

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.test.SSLTest.getCertificateExpiration(SSLTest.java:39)
at com.test.SSLTest.main(SSLTest.java:21)
```

Comment: SSL certificates are tied to domain names, it makes little sense to try and use HTTPS with an IP address - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33419662/1427878

Comment: @CBroe That doesn't explain a 'protocol version' error.

Comment: @OP Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @EJP If the server is configured as a virtual host, it might require SNI to access it via HTTPS.  Accessing it via an IP address would not set a host name for SNI.

Comment: @EJB Stacktrace updated

Comment: Does 192.168.1.1 really have a domain name? Or are you comparing what happens when you connect to two different hosts?

Comment: @AndrewHenle That would not explain a `protocol_version` alert: 'protocol_version:
       The protocol version the client has attempted to negotiate is
       recognized, but not supported. (For example, old protocol
       versions might be avoided for security reasons). This message is
       always fatal.'

Comment: Is it possible that the domain name is tied to a specific port different than 80?

Comment: @Jorge how would I get to know that? When i access the url via broswer I only give 192.168.1.1 and it displays the page correctly.. Also IPgiven hereis just an example. Actual IP that I am trying is different​.

Comment: Well that would be a possible cause. If you don't know who is the admin for the domain you are trying to check the certificate that's a problem.