# SSLError: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, branch.io

I'm making the following call to branch.io

```
import requests
req = requests.get('https://bnc.lt/m/H3XKyKB3Tq', verify=False)
```

It works fine in my local machine but fails in the server.

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

**Openssl versions:**

local: OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015

server: OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

**Python**:

local: 2.7.10
server: 2.7.6

**Branch io server connection**:

Chrome verified that DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA issued this website's certificate. The server did not supply any Certificate Transparency information.

I tried urllib2, but the result was same. Any help?

Comment: You need OpenSSL 0.9.8o at least to handle sha256 certificates so your server version is too old.

Comment: I tried on OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013. Its giving me the same error.

Comment: And is your PHP using that version of OpenSSL? See here for details on how to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7

Comment: Its using OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

Comment: This also can be an SNI issue, as `openssl s_client -connect bnc.lt:443` doesn't work while `openssl s_client -connect bnc.lt:443 -servername bnc.lt` works well. I'd say that both SHA2 signed cert and SNI can cause the issue, but the resolution is the same: update OpenSSL

Comment: You are using 6 year old software to provide your users with a 'secure' connection? Maybe you should not offer ssl at all rather, to not provide a false sense of security. Check http://openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html
So this is not even a question, just update your software, and the only version to consider is the most recent supported version.

Comment: @Nappy I had this issue with OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010 as well. We are already working on updating the certificate across the servers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Jyo de Lys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5172809/jyo-de-lys) has identified the problem. The problem is described [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/#what-are-hostname-doesn-t-match-errors) and the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484). I did the following to get this working:

1. easy_install pyOpenSSL
2. easy_install ndg-httpsclient
3. easy_install pyasn1

If you're getting this error while using urllib2, you'll need to upgrade to python 2.7.9 or later too.

Comment: I needed:

pip install pyasn1 

as well, to remove some "subjectAltName check for SSL peer verification will be disabled" warnings, but otherwise bang on and saved me much headscratching.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing ndg-httpsclient !

Comment: In case this doesn't solve the problem. Fixing pyOpenSSL to 0.13 it does

Comment: I had the same problem/error using the request package and Python 2.7.6 (Linux Mint 17.3), I followed this answer and the error vanished. Thank you

Comment: @Félix: Can you describe what you mean by "fixing pyOpenSSL to 0.13", including how to do that? Do you mean not allowing 0.13.1?

Comment: but this problem only on nginx in xampp problem not exists

Answer (score 1):

for those who are working on python 3.9 and you are facing this issue  "SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] "
while getting certificate or fetching expiry date for particular url

so you have to follow this steps in order to get valid response from the url

1. install openssl in windows
2. now copy the folder path of openssl which is being installed in C drive

use below code

servers is list of url
and ports is list of all ports in my case

```
for i in range(0,len(servers)):
    try:
        s = servers[i]
        port = ports[i]
        print("querying {}".format(s))
        q = Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.exe", "s_client", "-connect","{}:{}".format(s,port),"-servername",s,"-showcerts" ], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=False)
        y = check_output(["C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.exe", "x509", "-noout", "-dates"], stdin=q.stdout)
        print(y.decode("utf-8"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```