# sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)?

Tags: python, django, macos, paypal

This is my code:

```
def test(request):
    paypalrestsdk.configure({
      "mode": "security-test-sandbox",
        "client_id": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
        "client_secret": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"  })

    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
      "intent": "sale",
      "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
          "credit_card": {
            "type": "visa",
            "number": "4417119669820331",
            "expire_month": "11",
            "expire_year": "2018",
            "cvv2": "874",
            "first_name": "Joe",
            "last_name": "Shopper" }}]},
      "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
          "items": [{
            "name": "item",
            "sku": "item",
            "price": "1.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 1 }]},
        "amount": {
          "total": "1.00",
          "currency": "USD" },
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

    if payment.create():
      print("Payment created successfully")
    else:
      print(payment.error)
    return render(request, "test.html")
```

When performing the command `payment.create()` the error is:
`[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)`
I'm using Mac.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the solution but you shouldn't be using SSLv3 or any SSL due to security reasons. You should be using TSL. In any case, there is a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) to a question similar to this (`sslv3 alert handshake failure (-ssl.c:590)`)

Comment: how can I use TSL, please show me how!!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure?lq=1) might be useful to you.