# How to request a career page url within the domain using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import requests
s = ['jobs','careers','opportunities']
u = ['yahoo.com','statestreet.com']
f = []

for i in u:
    for j in s:
        w = "http://{}/{}".format(i,j)
        print w
        r = requests.get(w)
        print r.status_code
            if(r.status_code == 200):
                f.append(w)
                break
        print f
```

This code is working for most websites but not for websites like www.surveymonkey.com.

Comment: How is it not working (for www.surveymonkey.com)?  Is there an error message, or does it not behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what isn't working, or what you expect the code to do.  However, the indentation in the final `if` statement in your code seems incorrect.

Correcting that (and editing the variable names to be more descriptive as follows) at least runs as expected for me:

```
import requests

paths = ['jobs', 'careers', 'opportunities']
domains = ['yahoo.com', 'statestreet.com', 'surveymonkey.com']
results = []

for domain in domains:
    for path in paths:
        url = "http://{}/{}".format(domain, path)
        print url
        r = requests.get(url)
        print r.status_code
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
            results.append(url)
            break
print results
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Most of the domains are working with this code but not survey monkey.

Comment: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: Surveymonkey works fine for me in the above code.  Can you access http://surveymonkey.com/jobs directly from the machine you are developping on?  What site gave the error you posted?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) may help with the SSLV3 Handshake failure.