# BeautifulSoup error with requests.get() "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape this particular link ("https://fmovies.is/search?keyword=Kung+Fu+Panda+2") when I started getting this error "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure" .

I tried following the directions in the documentation https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 , python 2.7.6 and openssl version 1.01

Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to scrape websites such as these.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: The requests library seems to work.

Comment: @yosemite_k , yeah I tried updating everything.. didn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a purge on openssl and reinstalled from here https://www.openssl.org/source/ worked for me. I'm not really sure what the source of error was bit it's working fine now.

Thank you for all the help !