# How to solve sslv3 alert handshake failure during hg clone called from go get?

Tags: go, mercurial, clone

I am trying to install package for golang using the following command:

```
go get github.com/go-redis/redis
```

However, I got the following error:

```
go: bitbucket.org/zombiezen/gopdf@v0.0.0-20150317163809-1c63dc69751b: hg clone -U https://bitbucket.org/zombiezen/gopdf . in $GOPATH/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/296ef794d9a4113ffd8a947e0289b60e1e2cdeaebc09fe0be1f071e0ced6dbaf: exit status 255:
abort: error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

go: error loading module requirements

It seems that hg clone is failing.

I tried few other package installation, such as:

```
go get bitbucket.org/zombiezen/gopdf/pdf
hg clone -U https://bitbucket.org/zombiezen/gopdf
hg clone https://github.com/golang/oauth2
```

But it produces the same error, which is `abort: error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)`

I have tried this solution: [SSLError: sslv3 alert handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure)

But it does not work on my case.

Anyone can help?

Comment: bitbucket.org does not support ssl3 (it is not considered secure anymore), and for some reason mercurial doesn't negotiate a more modern TLS version. Which version of hg is installed and how did you install it?

Comment: Had same problem.  solved by updating the mercurial to latest version.

Comment: @boedrs If you need to update `hg` and you are using Ubuntu, you can do it with [this PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases)