# Run python packages failed

Tags: python

edit:
I tried the method in the comment section and now the problem becomes:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawlertest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Stylesheet'
```

I tried to install beautifulsoup4 with
`pip3 install beautifulsoup4` but it said
"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:720) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4"
Then I tried `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and then installed again and succeeded.I also installed the package "requests".
But later when I tried  to run requests and beautifulsoup4 on my Mac but it showed something like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked,
```

and something like

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:720)
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the base certificates installed.

Go to:

`Macintosh HD > Applications > Python3.x`

And run Install `Certificates.command`

Also, refer the following links:

[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52805115/11589805)

https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1682