# Pyhton requests.post raise error SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)')

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) solution but it didn't work

I'm doing a POST requests in the form of

```
res = requests.post(
            url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.headers, verify=False
        )
```

But I'm getting `SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)')`

I'm using pyhton 3.10 with

- pyOpenSSL 23.2.0
- requests 2.31.0

I've tried

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

Doing `openssl s_client -connect 10.10.96.28:443`

```
SSL handshake has read 1010 bytes and written 611 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Everything works in Python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the library that has been fixed

https://github.com/JurajNyiri/pytapo/issues/65#issuecomment-1656470805