Python3 Extracting HTML Data from Webpage
I am trying to extract HTML data from the webpage shown in the code below. Other websites work, but the one shown in the code below causes an error. What is causing the error?
This is the code
import requests

url = 'https://clasificadosonline.com/'  # URL of the webpage to scrape

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status() 
    html_content = response.text

    # Print the HTML content
    print(html_content)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Request failed: {e}")


except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Request failed: {e}")

This is the error I am getting.
"C:\Users\17874\OneDrive - University of Puerto Rico\Desktop\WebScraping\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\17874\OneDrive - University of Puerto Rico\Desktop\WebScraping\venv\Clasificados Online.py" 
Request failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='clasificadosonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)')))
Process finished with exit code 0
'''


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405092/sslerror-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure perhaps isn't an exact duplicate, but definitely tells you where to look. If nothing else, it reveals what sorts of details to include in your question.

did you try using selenium?

Try to force SSL connection with DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 ciphers:
import ssl
import warnings

import requests
import requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions as urllib3_exceptions

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", urllib3_exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


class TLSAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.set_ciphers("DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1")
        ctx.options |= 0x4
        kwargs["ssl_context"] = ctx
        return super(TLSAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


url = "https://clasificadosonline.com/"  # URL of the webpage to scrape


with requests.session() as s:
    s.mount("https://", TLSAdapter())

    response = s.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    html_content = response.text

    print(html_content)

Prints:
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--

    

if (screen.width <= 480) {

document.location = "https://www.clasificadosonline.com/m/";

}



//-->

</script>

<html><!-- #BeginTemplate "/Templates/master.dwt" --><!-- DW6 -->

...


Thank you so much! I tried it and it works! Sorry for the delay I just got back from vacation. I appreciate the response.
