# Google App Engine client SNI support python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, sni

I'm writing an application in Google App Engine, and I'm trying to send HTTPS requests (GET / POST) from GAE to a private server.

Is there any method to achieve a request with:
- sending request with client certificate/key;
- verify server certificate;
AND using SNI support?

I'v tried to use:

- urllib2 -> but it can't verifies server CA;
- urlfetch -> it only verifies server CA;
- urllib3 -> i'm getting 
  "_ssl.c:529: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed", caused by missing SNI support;
- lib requests -> same of urllib3.

I'v also tried for SNI to put libraries on Google App Engine as indicated in [using requests with TLS doesn't give SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484)

- pyOpenSSL
- ndg-httpsclient
- pyasn1

But pyOpenSSL has C dependencies, so there is no way to use it, and it's not supported as third party library.

TL;DR: sending request from GAE to private server in SSL with client cert, verify server CA and SNI support seems to be impossible.
I think the matter is:

- python version in GAE, that is 2.7.5 and not 2.7.9 (with backported SNI compatibilty).
- maybe also SSL version included in GAE is not supporting SNI ( ssl has not HAS_SNI attr)

How can I do that?