# requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)

Tags: python, macos, ssl, curl

I did

```
import requests

url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
data = requests.get(url).json()


print data
```

I kept getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/curl.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = requests.get(url).json()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

BUT if I run this **`curl https://randomuser.me/api/`**

on my Terminal, I got

```
{"results":[{"gender":"male","name":{"title":"mr","first":"joscha","last":"maier"},"location":{"street":"7686 parkstraße","city":"kelheim","state":"hessen","postcode":46836},"email":"joscha.maier@example.com","login":{"username":"bluefrog937","password":"2003","salt":"xcZH4xOX","md5":"9fc3a4c2c8999066149d322ab4948669","sha1":"1c392831338c7b5715bd19a4c186111df32a6d04","sha256":"a21b5afa260d8d6a121d6f2dc688fb2f2b41e4f0b5c823daea76f968338653fb"},"dob":"1994-10-26 06:51:40","registered":"2009-05-25 10:37:41","phone":"0509-5347389","cell":"0174-6616884","id":{"name":"","value":null},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/26.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/26.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg"},"nat":"DE"}],"info":{"seed":"f74c00ae752dccac","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.1"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me with Python 2.7.12. You are not giving the exact version of Python you are using but my guess is that it is a version before 2.7.9. In 2.7.9 several changes to the SSL implementation where done, including adding support for [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Your target URL needs support for SNI in the client as can be seen when testing the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=randomuser.me&s=104.31.90.126&latest):

> This site works only in browsers with SNI support.

The trace you show is typical for clients which don't support SNI. 
From the [FAQ for requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/):

> Python3 and Python 2.7.9+ include native support for SNI in their SSL modules. For information on using SNI with Requests on Python < 2.7.9 refer to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484).

Comment: My python version `/usr/bin/python --version` --> 
Python 2.7.10

Comment: @ihue: which version of OpenSSL `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` and requests `requests.__version__` ?

Comment: If you don't mind, I ask, how do I check for those 2 info ?

Comment: @ihue: I thought it was clear from my comment but [see here](https://pastebin.com/JRPMfUXe) for the complete python code you could use.