# "hostname doesn't match" when using requests in PythonAnywhere

Tags: ssl, python-requests, pyopenssl

**EDIT**: I fixed the problem, see links in the answer.

I'm using the *XMLHttpRequest* AJAX API to send data from different websites to our server in PythonAnywhere. 
Something odd happens: depending on the website, either we send successfully or we get this error

```
POST https://canecto.pythonanywhere.com/api/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

even though the same code is loaded.
I tried to manually open the request and send data via JavaScript console in Chrome but nothing changes.

Here is how the snippet looks like:

```
var url = "https://canecto.pythonanywhere.com/api/";
var xmlHttpPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpPost.open("POST", url, true);
xmlHttpPost.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

var postData = {
    page_url: window.location.href,
    time_on_page: activeTime,
    cookie: cookie,
    /* some variables */
};
xmlHttpPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttpPost.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log('');
    }
};

/* send data */
xmlHttpPost.send(JSON.stringify(postData));
```

I read [here](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/500-internal-server-error) that the problem should not be the client-side JavaScript.

If I inspect on the server side, for the line `requests.get(page_url, headers=HEADER, timeout=10)`(where I try to access the page) I get this log:

[image]

I read on the [Python request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/) that it may be something related to the SSL verification, but I have very little clue about it. I tried to check other similar questions but I have not found the answer.

Has anybody experienced anything similar and successfully solved it?

Comment: seems like I found something interesting in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579484/4146521) but I need to check if works once installed the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To whom it still uses Python < 2.7.9**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579484/4146521) worked for me. SNI is not supported in Python 2, that means you should follow such answer and [these requirements](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/749#issuecomment-19187417) to make requests work with SSL certificate verification.

Comment: "these instructions" 404.

Comment: @rschwieb unfortunately the url has gone, but I linked the comment where it had originated. There, you can find the requirements for it to work.