# Trying to make a post request with python, but keep getting this error. When I make the request in postman it works fine

Tags: python, python-requests

```py
import requests
url = "https://services.contaazul.com/app/finance/v1/category/activation/revenues"
payload_receita = {"dueDateFrom":"2023-01-01","dueDateTo": None,"quickFilter":"ALL","search": None,"references":["SALE","SALE_SCHEDULED"],"type":"REVENUE"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Authorization': '49dda07f-7861-47d3-a0b6-cdb7a77f5ec5'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='services.contaazul.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /app/finance/v1/category/activation/revenues (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\OneDrive - HYPER\Área de Trabalho\testes\teste2.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Marques -Hyper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='services.contaazul.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /app/finance/v1/category/activation/revenues (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

Comment: Format your code, it's unreadable, also take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484